# leaving something out of a meal zecher lachurban

Tags: food, mourning-aveilus, meal-seudah, churban-destruction

As described in [משנה ברורה ס׳ תקס ס״ק ה–ו–ז](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=74), we omit something from any big meal (not on Shabas or yom tov), noticeably, as a זכר לחרבן. Has anyone seen this done, and, if so, *what* was omitted? I'm looking for ideas on what to omit. (This will presumably be dependent on the type of meal and the format of the meal, so that an informal brunch in someone's house (assuming this halacha applies to it) will need to have something different omitted than a typical wedding. Anything seen at any type of meal will be great.)

Comment: I've always hoped to see an empty spot at a wedding's "shmorg".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was at a wedding where they did not serve soup and there were placecards on the table that stated the reason was because of the aformentioned reason and had the Shuchan Aruch written out; I was intrigued as until then I had not heard of it.